# ListView With Grouping Headers Sub Group solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, listview, c#-3.0

I was working with Listview and Displaying data with Grouping Headers like in image [image: trip shhet] , but I want to display sub records to be also grouped like based on TicketNo (i.e common Ticket No should be grouped and display as single record) like bellow can any one guide me how to achieve this  .

> 1 KT90914 , L1(F),L2(F),R1(F),R2(F) ,Ghoousunnisa ,9951067850, Nellore, 2200, 220, 1980

Comment: solution for this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d9c87a/listview-with-group-headers-in-Asp-Net/

Answer (score 0):

Search the salstat2 [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/salstat-statistics-package-2/wiki/PivotData) then download the src and use the library slbTools which contains the class GroupData equivalent to class group of the wiki reference

for example:

```
from slbTools import GroupData
res= GroupData()
col0= ['name_col0', 'KT90914', 'KT90914', 'KT90914', 'KT90914', 'KT90914']
col1= ['name_col1',  'L1(F)', 'L2(F)', 'R1(F)','R2(F)']
res.xdata= [col0,]
res.ydata= [col1 ,]
res.yalias= ['Tiket',]
res.yvalues= ['concat(Tiket)']
lista=  res.getAsRow()
for row in lista:
   print row
```

Finally you should obtain this

```
['name_col0', 'Tiket']
('KT90914', 'L1(F); L2(F); R1(F); R2(F)')
```

so with a few painting you should find what you want.